# Xamarin.IOS plugin, view bundle resources in DLL

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, embedded-resource

Xamarin.IOS plugin in VS2019, how can I view in a DLL or output what bundle resources are actually in the output or DLL and what folder there are under?

I'm trying to debug issues, and while the output of the MSBUILD diagnostic gives alot of detail, I'm uncertain where and if it put my resources in the output.

Is there a viewer?  Doesn't show in Object browser.

Comment: If I understand right, you can check the  bundle resources in the ipa of iOS after archive.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked IPA as well as Assets.car and that makes it clearer, I'm not getting some files there.  If I have an SDK plugin/project, then import that into my main Xamarin IOS, where does the resources from that plugin/project go?  That's what I'm missing and can't find anywhere.

Comment: You can't see those plugin/project/codes, they are stored in binary files.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really stuck, as I can't find out why my resources aren't available to read with UIImage read.  My original post. 
 I've spent about a week trying to get this plugin to work with newer SDK style using James M. example, and my last step for IOS just isn't finding the resource.. 
 Any advice on how to diagnose would be extremely helpful. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497104/xamarin-plugin-sdk-style-ios-project-uikit-uiimage-method-returns-a-nill-and-doe